# For loop changing style of first item only

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a pure javascript content slider and I'm stuck in the same issue for almost two hours.

The loop is supposed to position all "container" divs beside each other for future sliding.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VinnyFonseca/4sTtY/3/)

```
var sliderWidth = sliderActive[0].offsetWidth;

for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
    container[i].style.left = sliderWidth * i;
}
```

Cannot figure out why it loops only once. Any ideas?

Comment: does it loop only once or does it change only the first element? There could be a huge difference there. Have you tried `console.log` in the `for`-loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the `for`-loop. It's actually setting the `left` property correctly, but a number alone (other than 0) isn't a valid value for this property.

Try specifying a unit for the style, like this:

```
container[i].style.left = (sliderWidth * i) + 'px';
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was breaking my head, and I forgot I'm setting inline styles doing that so a unit should be specified. It works, thanks a lot.